# solve for x within a summation equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I am Only in Algebra II Trig and am just getting into these kinds of things. So please forgive me if my terminology or notation are wrong.

So, Say I have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n} x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ Which is the Taylor series for $\sin x$

But I take that and set it equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Which obviously would evaluate to 1, (evaluate is the word?) anyways, how would I solve for $x$ when it's inside of a series (series is the word?) Basically I'm evaluating $\sin x = 1$ using the series for $\sin$

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, I'm unable to search for it because I don't know what the name of what I'm doing is.

Comment: Obviously, I know $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ But I want to know how to figure it out this way

Comment: @user oops I thought I made that $\frac{1}{2^n}$ I'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of "solving for an $x$ inside a sum" would be to find a closed form for that sum, and then solve an equation. As you probably have guessed, there are cases when this is not possible. In such cases, one can come up with approximate solutions looking some special or dominant terms of the series.

If you want to solve $\sin x=1$, using series seems overkill, and actually it seems the other way around. Just solve this as a regular equation. This equation can be solved looking at the behaviour of the sine function, which is a periodic function. You know by trigonometry that $\sin(\pi/2)=1$, so $\pi/2$ is a solution. Do you know of other values that evaluate to 1? Think of the unit circle.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know how I would solve for it if it were a different value. Also, I noticed those equal signs were a typo and fixed them.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of $\sin(5\pi/2)$? And why?

Comment: Oh.... Because it's $2\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$. So it really is unsolvable because x can be an $\infty$ amount of things. But couldn't I make a series the solution? How about making $$x = f(n) = n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$ Or whatever the proper notation is. How would one arrive upon that answer?

Comment: Well, it is solvable, it only has an infinite number of possible solutions. A linear equation has only one solution. A quadratic equation has two posible solutions. Your equation has an infinite number of solutions. Good work, you're close. But beware of the form you are stating. It includes $-\pi/2$ which is not a solution!

Comment: $x = f(n) = n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \space \text{if} \space x\ge0$ I couldn't figure out how to do a piece wise so I did this *Edit:* this is wrong because $\frac{-3\pi}{2}$ is still a solution. Edit2: Wait but $-1\pi+\frac{-\pi}{2} = \frac{-3\pi}{2}$

Comment: so $x = f(n) = [n]\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: But how would I retrieve that from a Taylor series is my whole question.

Comment: Actually $x=2\pi n+ \pi/2$ for any integer $n$. Good work

Comment: Taylor series is a representation, not a way of "solving equations" as you may suggest

Comment: Oh. Well I'm not sure if it's called a sum or a Taylor series. So it's just a way to represent what $\sin x$ is? Maybe someone should invent a way to set it equal to something and solve for a value inside.

Comment: What you wrote is a sum and also a Taylor series. Yes, it ia just a representation, and it is not meant for algebraic purposes. It rather gives you insight about how the function behaves.